# How can I create stomp subscription using spring integration TCP Inbound Gateway?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, stomp

Consider I have a TCP server built using spring integration (TCP Inbound Gateway), which is used as request/response kind of server with the TCP connection is initiated from client (also built using spring integration) which the TCP connection is maintained and shared.

Is there a way to create stomp subscription in the same TCP inbound gateway?

Answer (score 1):

Would be great if you share more background on the matter, but I think you can do any stuff within the downstream flow from the `request-channel` of that `<int-ip:tcp-inbound-gateway>`. E.g. `<router>` or `<recipient-list-router>`, `<publish-subscribe-channel>` etc.

Comment: So I have TCP inbound gateway which receive request and reply with response. My use case is that along with that request/response, while the connection is opened, it client is also subscribing to changes in data. When data is changed at server, it should be published to the client that the data it was requested has changed. I'm thinking of using stomp based subscription, but I'm still blurred how to achieve that with spring-integration designed as mentioned above.